# Align top edge of Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu with bottom edge of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown menu to appear directly beneath the navigation bar, but by default it appears slightly above the bottom edge of the navigation bar.

Is there a way to achieve this without setting a fixed height for the navbar and using margin-top on the dropdown-menu?

If I remember correctly, the default in Bootstrap 3 was to align the top edge of the dropdown with the bottom edge of the navbar. This seems to have changed in BS 4.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg flex-row shadow">
     <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-desktop flex-row ml-auto d-none d-lg-inline-flex">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navSearchDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navSearchDropdown">
                <div class="px-2">
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

UPDATE:

As I mentioned I did not want to add any margin to the top of the dropdown menu as this would not work across all screen sizes without setting a fixed height for the navbar, which isn't ideal.

I achieved what I wanted using the following:

```
.navbar {
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar .container {
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Then adding padding to the brand and each nav-link as required.

Comment: did you try setting `padding` or `margin` to `0` for the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can add margin to for dropdown-menu. you have to give important because dropdown-menu has its default margin:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
 margin: 8px 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown flex-row justify-content-md-center justify-content-start flex-nowrap">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu ">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust it with `top`.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
}
```